# Best way to rewrite statement or avoid using a specific index

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

This issue is double edged. On test system this query returns in about 7 mins. On my reporting system that has the same indexes plus addition columnstore indexes to cover additional problem reports it doesn't want to return at all as its selected to use the columnstore indexes.

1) Can I use a CTE or something slicker to accomplish this TSQL? I can't seem to improve performance without changing the logic.

```
SELECT Count(BookingId)   
from Booking_tbl b1
WHERE email IN (Select Email From Booking_tbl b2 WHERE DateDiff(day, b2.BookedDate ,       b1.BookedDate) > 1)
```

2) can I stop the engine using a particular index ?  I know I can set it to INDEX(0) to use no indexes or name a specific index, but can I say 'for this query, don't use this specific index!'

was torn to put this on SO or DBA SE

Basically I need to count the number of repeat bookings to get a percentage.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to count e-mails which has BookedDate more than one day apart.

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT email FROM Booking_tbl
GROUP BY email
HAVING DateDiff(day, MIN(BookedDate) ,MAX(BookedDate)) > 1
) as T
```

To get it faster you should create indexes on `BookedDate` and `email` fields.